# Dedekind's axiom for a general relation

Tags: real-analysis, logic, foundations

My book gives the *Dedekind's axiom or law of continuity*, only for the $<$ relation:

> If $S$ and $T$ are any sets of numbers (that is $S\subseteq R$ and $T\subseteq R$) satisfying the condition:
>
> For any $x\in S$ and any $y\in T$ we have: $x < y$
>   then there exists a number $z$ which the following condition holds for:
>
> If $x\in S$ and any $y\in T$, and if $x\ne z$ and $y\ne z$, then $x < z$ and $z < y$

Then it says:

> To state a general condition for the relation $R$ to be continuous in the class $K$, replace in the preceding law "$ R$" by "$K$" and the word "number" by "element of the set $K$" and "$<$" by "$R$", but how do you do that? What happens to the $\ne$ ?
>
> If $S$ and $T$ are any sets (that is $S\subseteq K$ and $T\subseteq K$) satisfying the condition:
>
> For any $x\in S$ and any $y\in T$ we have: $xRy$,
>   then there exists an element $z\in K$ which the following condition holds for: 
>   if $x\in S$ and any $y\in T$, and if $x\ne z$ and $y\ne z$, then $xRz$ and $zRy$

Comment: What book are you using?

Comment: @Noah Schweber Introduction to Logic: And to the Methodology of Deductive Sciences by Tarski

Comment: $=$ and $\neq$ are already well defined for elements of any set. So there is no problem.

Comment: @Paramanand Singh so stating it as I did at the end is correct?

Comment: Yes the statement at the end is correct.